# Removing Webpack's module wrapper to produce a pure JS script

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm using `webpack` to bundle some simple JS files / modules.

The webpack output (unminified) looks like:

```js
(self["webpackChunktest-project"] = self["webpackChunktest-project"] || []).push([[179],{

/***/ 4:
/***/ (() => {


// ...
// <MY BUNDLED CODE HERE>
// ...


/***/ })

},
/******/ __webpack_require__ => { // webpackRuntimeModules
/******/ "use strict";
/******/ 
/******/ var __webpack_exec__ = (moduleId) => (__webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = moduleId))
/******/ var __webpack_exports__ = (__webpack_exec__(4));
/******/ }
]);
```

As you can see, it wraps my code in some webpack modularization logic.

**Is there any way to remove this wrapper logic?** I'd love to just produce a pure JS file as an output without the boilerplate wrapper.

**NOTE:** Because I set [`optimzation.runtimeChunk`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationruntimechunk) to `true` (see config below), `webpack` creates a *separate* runtime file (not shown here), and the minimally wrapped JS file shown above.

## Webpack Config

Here is the `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
    runtimeChunk: true
  },
  output: {
    path: DIST_DIR
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: [SRC_DIR, 'node_modules']
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: ['node_modules']
  },
  entry: `${SRC_DIR}/test.js`,
  module: {},
  plugins: []
};
```

Comment: "*I'd love to just produce a pure JS file as an output without the boilerplate wrapper.*" Maybe tangential to your question, but can you expand on why this is a requirement for you?

Comment: @esqew - I'd like to produce a script that can run on a cloud service like Google Sheets.. I kept it out of scope for this question because that's sort of a fixed requirement for me, I'm just wondering if it's possible via webpack. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity!